# Design patterns collect data from different databases

Tags: database, design-patterns

actually, i want to collect informations from different sources of data (csv files, databases...), if we don't find the information in one of the sources we will search in  an other one,
I tried to find a design pattern to solve this problem, Is there some well known design pattern to make us of?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use adapter pattern.

**Target** - defines the domain-specific interface that Client uses.

**Client** - collaborates with objects conforming to the Target interface.

**Adaptee** - defines an existing interface that needs adapting.

**Adapter** - adapts the interface of Adaptec to the Target interface.

[image]